# Symfony2: Run code to create directories after cache clear

Tags: php, symfony

I use a twig template directory at $SFROOT/var/cache/$ENVIRONMENT/templates to store generated twig templates.

In the twig configuration, i added this directory so templates are found.

When clearing the cache, the directory is not created automatically

All console commands, including composer post-install cache-clear hooks, fail because twig requires that directory to exist, but after a cache clear it doesn't.

How to I ensure the directory gets created after the cache is cleared?

I'm looking for some sort of dependencyinjection to add a hook to post-cache-clear (google returned nothing) with a mkdir command, but am unable to find out how to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Custom Cache Warmer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-cache-warmer)

```
// src/Acme/MainBundle/Cache/MyCustomWarmer.php
namespace AppBundle\Cache;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerInterface;

class MyCustomWarmer implements CacheWarmerInterface
{
    public function warmUp($cacheDir)
    {
        // ... do some sort of operations to "warm" your cache
    }

    public function isOptional()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

custom service:

```
services:
    app.warmer.my_custom_warmer:
        class: AppBundle\Cache\MyCustomWarmer
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.cache_warmer, priority: 0 }
```